# FileReader Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I am trying to upload image in **component A** and send base 64 data of uploaded image to **component B**. I am facing issue in **component A**

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="file" id="hotspot" (change)="uploadHotSpot($event)">
```

**TS File:**

```
 uploadHotSpot($event){
    var file:File = $event.target.files[0]; 
    var reader:FileReader = new FileReader();

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
      this.pin = reader.result;
      console.log(this.pin);
    }
}
```

**Issue:** When I upload the image and keep developer tool on, I am able to get the base 64 data on console log but when the debugger tool is closed and I am trying to upload the image I am getting console.log as blank..... Any idea?

Comment: Quick question : if you only share the image between two components, why don't you just send the image instead of the base64 ?

Comment: I am not sure about your question. What I am trying to do is user is uploading image on component A which will be visible in component B

Comment: Then why are you converting it to base64 ? You don't need to.

Comment: what is the approach then can u guide?

Comment: Well for starters, maybe you should provide a [mcve], because right now, you don't even have two components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's now how it works. You should create an `onload` callback to get the result. Like so :

```js
uploadHotSpot($event) {
    var file:File = $event.target.files[0]; 
    var reader:FileReader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      this.pin = reader.result;
      console.log(this.pin);
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
    }
}
```